# My sql query optimization on simple query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have query

```
SELECT r.*,u.name AS name, u.username AS username 
FROM jos_js_res_record AS r 
LEFT JOIN jos_users AS u on u.id = r.user_id 
LEFT JOIN jos_js_res_record_values AS f on f.record_id = r.id AND f.field_type = 'digits'
AND f.field_label = 'Price' 
WHERE r.section_id = 2 
AND MATCH (fieldsdata) AGAINST ('article' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
AND r.title like 'A%' 
ORDER BY f.field_value + 0 desc, f.field_value desc
```

I do not know why but it produce in explain 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort. I did all I know to optimize this query but no result. As far as I understand it is because joined `jos_js_res_record_values` and `ORDER BY`. If I comment `ORDER BY` or change it to `ORDER BY r.created`  Using temporary goes away.

Comment: Why do you use `ORDER BY f.field_value + 0`? Is it an `ENUM` column?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you do any type of ORDER BY operation and amend a value with a function/math (+0), you're going to force MySQL to do a transformation on every field in the result set, thus why you're getting the `temporary`.

Can you post the structure of your tables so we can see what indexes and field types you have?

Answer (score 0):

We have to pay attention with queries with `LEFT JOIN`. This kind of `JOIN` have to be used on table right `indexed`. Do you checked your `indexes` ??

If their are okay and your tables have too many rows, it may cause lattency on you query even if it most optimized as possible.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create an index for the following fields:
jos_users.id
jos_js_res_record_values.record_id
jos_js_res_record_values.field_type
jos_js_res_record_values.field_label
jos_js_res_record.section_id
fieldsdata
jos_js_res_record.title

2.)
This should be taken out from the join and should be put in the where:

```
f.field_type = 'digits'
AND f.field_label = 'Price'
```

3.) where A and B:
If A is not probable (it's rare in the table) and it's calculated quicker than B, then this is a good order. Otherwise where B and A is faster than where A and B.
The same is true for or, but there it's better to have a more probability for left-side operands, because of these formulas:

```
False and B = False
True or B = True
```

In the cases where the above formula is applicable B is not calculated at all and you win a lot of time. So, if you patiently test your operands with more value types you can get the ideal order.

4.) Instead of this:

```
ORDER BY f.field_value + 0 desc, f.field_value desc
```

you need this:

```
ORDER BY f.field_value desc, f.field_value desc
```

if the former is not forced by anything.

I hope this helps.